# jQuery show & hide elements in table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling a little bit with the following. I have a table with 2 rows and within the rows three TD's. Each td contains and `<img>` and a `<div class="overlay">`.

Some of the `.overlay` divs are open by default. **I want these to close too if there is a click on a TD**.

**Goal:**
If you click on an TD a want to open/show that particular overlay and close all others (also the overlay's that are open by default). The `<img/>` can stay where it is.

**HTML Structure**

```
<table id="table_overview">
  <tr>
     <td><img src="foo.jpg"/><div class="overlay">text</div></td>
     <td><img src="foo.jpg"/><div class="overlay hidden">text</div></td>
     <td><img src="foo.jpg"/><div class="overlay hidden">text</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><img src="foo.jpg"/><div class="overlay hidden">text</div></td>
     <td><img src="foo.jpg"/><div class="overlay hidden">text</div></td>
     <td><img src="foo.jpg"/><div class="overlay">text</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery** (not working well)

```
$(#table_overview td).each(function(){
   $(this).on('click', function(){
       if($(this).find('.overlay').hasClass('hidden')){
          $(this).find('.overlay').show();
       }
   }, function(){
       // second click on td close this overlay.
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that it is the hidden class that hides the overlay, so just toggle the hidden class

```
$("#table_overview tr td").each(function(){
   $(this).on('click', function(){
       $(this).find('.overlay').toggleClass('hidden');
   });
});
```

or simply

```
$("#table_overview tr td").on('click', function(){
       $(this).find('.overlay').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

If you want to close all other overlay div's that are not hidden for a particular row, then

```
$("#table_overview tr td").on('click', function(){
       $(this).parent().find('.overlay').addClass( "hidden" );
       $(this).find('.overlay').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

If you want to close all other overlay div's that are not hidden for complete table, then

$("#table_overview tr td").on('click', function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().find('.overlay').addClass( "hidden" );
       $(this).find('.overlay').removeClass('hidden');
});

Comment: Yes this works fine. except that i want to close all other overlay div's that are not hidden.

Comment: I tried the last code (for the complete table.) But it not shows the overlay on the clicked element. maybe because I first need to know if it already has a class "hidden"?